# Send HTML in email via PHP with datepicker values

Tags: php, html, forms, datepicker

I want to have a page with some form inputs and with date picker i want to send these all fields to mail how to i do this with PHP?

Comment: This is really two (or more) completely separate questions. There's nothing special about sending datepicker values to an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by first getting what users typed in a form.
Then parse the input into a text file or html file that you can send using the mail() function in PHP.

for example for a "datepickerfield" field:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $_GET['datepickerfield'];
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...im new to php so please tell detaily

Answer (score 0):

You can access the form input fields in PHP over [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). This depends on your form.

```
<form action="/mail.php" method="get">
```

or

```
<form action="/mail.php" method="post">
```

Here's an example:

HTML Form:

```
<form action="/mail.php" method="post">
  <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname">
  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and in your php file :

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


$message = 'The Birthday of '.$_POST['fullname'].' is: '.$_POST['birthday'];

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php